# Shopify Theme Development - Help me understand the 'files' URL

Tags: jquery, templates, shopify

I am developing a section that will need to pull images through from the 'files' folder.

I will have images `a.png`, `b.png` & `c.png` all saved within the 'files' folder. I will then loop through an array of image names `array = [a,b,c]`.

My first question is, as I loop through am I able to go to one of the 'files' directories, say for `a.png` with the file location of `file:///cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/a.png`

Can I grab the start of the file URL `file:///cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/` then put an `a` the value from the array in at the end?
`file:///cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/ + array[0] + .png`

The above is just how I plan to use the variable and already have successful code so long as the 'files' URL start remains the same, but can anyone explain the files URL to me? `file:///cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/`
What is the `/s/` + `/1/` + `/0043/` + `/0886/` + `/0977/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will be unique to your store here is a sample from a test store of mine

`https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0705/0149/files/mobile-receipt-debit.png`

Nothing is the same (except the files and 1).

If you plan to change them with JS you will need to use RegEx and swap only the name part of the image.

Comment: Thats what I did to generate the URL, but with liquid it is rendered before jQuery so I need to use a static URL without the liquid tags. The answer in short though, is those values will be static and unique to my store?

Comment: Yes they will be unique to your store here is a sample from a test store of mine https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0705/0149/files/mobile-receipt-debit.png nothing is the same (except the `files` and `1`). If you plan to change them with JS you will need to use RegEx and swap only the name part of the image.

Comment: Can you swap this to be your answer so I can give you credit, thanks for the help

Comment: @JasonIsMyName no problem.

Comment: Thanks, so no one knows what the random number named files are?

Comment: @JasonIsMyName there might be some logic behind them, but it's not publicly available. So no it's not known.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, upvote if you enjoyed my question c: